# how to set up Sustainability Cloud

Tags: licenses, developer-org

I am interested to try out Sustainability Cloud however I don't find anywhere I can set it up as a demo org, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [Configure and Install Sustainability Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sustainability_admin.htm&type=5) in your org.  Before installing the app verify that your org has the Sustainability Cloud permission set license. If it doesn’t, contact your account executive. Assign this permission set license to atleast one user.

Install Sustainability Cloud from [appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FuYUWUA3) listed.

Thanks